# unable to add more details of user and their picture in organizational google chart using mysqldata

Tags: php, json, google-api, google-visualization

I am creating  an organizational google chart using mysql data. I am able to retrieve  data from mysql database and show as an hierarchy, but the problem is i am unable display image of each person in that chart which are stored in the database. The child and parent data are stored in an array and im unable to display more details of the person in the chart. If i add an extra data which i got from mysql database, my code is taking only the 1st value and displaying only the person name, where i want to display more details of the person.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<?php

include_once('dbconfig.php');


$query = $connection->prepare('SELECT hierarchy.child,hierarchy.id,usertest.userID, usertest.name
                        FROM hierarchy
                        INNER JOIN usertest
                        ON hierarchy.userID=usertest.userID
                        ORDER BY hierarchy.id');
$query->execute();
$results = $query->get_result();

$flag = true;
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'child', 'type' => 'string','image'),
    array('label' => 'Parent', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'userID', 'type' => 'number', 'role' => 'tooltip','trigger'=>'selection' ),




);
$table['rows'] = array();

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array('v' =>  $row['child']);

    $temp[] = array('v' => $row['name']);
    $temp[] = array('v' =>  $row['userID']);





    $table['rows'][] = array('c' => $temp);
}

$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
?>

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>
        Google Visualization API Sample
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function drawVisualization() {
                // Create and populate the data table.
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $jsonTable; ?>);

                // Create and draw the visualization.
               var table = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
                table.draw(data, {legend:'none', width:10000, height:400,border: '#000000'});


            }

            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['orgchart']});

            google.visualization.events.addListener(table,'select', function() {
 alert('selected');
});
             // Add our over/out handlers.


        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="font-family: Arial;border: ;#000000">
        <div id="visualization" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; background: #000000;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example on the [API documentation page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart), the first element for the first two nodes is an array with fields 'v' and 'f'. 'v' is the value of the id for the node. 'f' is what is shown in that node. If you simply add all the information you want to display into the field associated with 'f', you should be able to display everything you want to.

You should concatenation the details together with whatever markup you like. For ex:

```
$temp[] = array('v' => $row['name'], 'f' => "<h3>{$row['id'] }</h3><p>{$row['picture'']}</p>");
```

If you want to use html tags like I do above, don't forget to pass the right option (allowHtml:true) to the .draw() function, like so:

```
chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
```

Comment: The problem is im unable to add more display more details of employee in the chart, because in the columns field i had mentioned according to the google org charts requirements. the second field in an array is always considered as parent.Because of this im unable to display the more details. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

Comment: In the example on the API documentation page you linked, the first element for the first two nodes is an array with fields 'v' and 'f'. 'v' is the value of the id for the node. 'f' is what is shown  in that node. If you simply add all the information you want to display into the field associated with 'f', you should be able to display everything you want to.

Comment: Hi thankyou so much and its working , can you tell me how to display multiple line or multiple details of a person. i am trying to write like this but it is displaying only the 1st value..   $temp[] = array('v' => $row['name'], 'f' => $row['id'], $row['picture']);

Comment: You should concatenation the details together with whatever markup you like. For ex: $temp[] = array('v' => $row['name'], 'f' => "<h3>{$row['id'] }</h3><p>{$row['picture'']}</p>");

Comment: Thankyou somuch nickRise please post ur answer in answer section, so that i can mark it

Comment: There is a small problem in this i am unable to echo out and write html tags, if i write in your way then tags are not working and even those tags are showing up in the tree row

Comment: @Sai As I just added to my answer, you'll want to pass the "allowHtml:true" option to the .draw() function if you want to use html tags.

Comment: Thankyou so much nickRise, I went to google visualization documentation and and found my mistake..

Comment: @Sai I'm glad I could help.